# Why isn't new sewer vent cap resolving poor toilet flushing?

Tags: toilet, vent, sewer

Next to my lakehouse is a renovated garage with a toilet and a sink. Entire structure was built in the 90s. We have septic. Toilet flushes poorly, gurgles with flushing and just randomly. Removed the sewer vent cap, which is under the sink, and the toilet flushes great. I purchased a new vent cap the next day. Expected the room to smell, and it did not. Threaded on the new vent cap, and toilet no longer flushes well. Removed it, and it's fine again! I'm at a loss for options and sure would appreciate anyone's ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toilet needs it's own vent pipe. You see them on roofs coming out. They are the vents for drain pipes.

Install one for your toilet.

What you call a sewer vent cap is actually where you connect the drain vent pipe up through the roof.

Since it is under the sink it is also the vent for the sink.

We call that incomplete installation.

If you do not like drilling holes in your roof, you can have it exit through the wall. Cover it with mosquito net to stop Lake monsters coming in. Then put a nice vent cap (vented) on it to make it look good.

Comment: This would not be the first instance of a "lake house" not being build to common building standards.